# How to run tests on AWS instance using Teamcity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, testing, teamcity, instance

I'm working on a C#/C++ project that need specific hardware architecture, therefore, event for unit testing, I can't run them in a standard docker; I need to use a specific AWS EC2 instance.
My current build steps are the following one:
Build Step 1: Teamcity is making the build in a local docker.
Build Step 2: Teamcity is uploading the the artifacts on S3.
Build Step 3: Teamcity is launching a specific AWS EC2 instance.

Now I want to tell Teamcity to run the tests on this specific instance and still following the progress of the tests to be able to send alerts.
Or, at least, I can manage the testing execution at instance Startup, then need information on the output format to send to Teamcity.

Regards